# Which preposition is correct here?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

- on September 29 2014
- in September 29 2014

I know with months, we should use *in*, and with days, we should use *on*. However I find the American way in writing the month before the day in dates to be confusing. Should we use *on* here because we are referring to a day or should we use *in* because it immediately precedes a month? *On* seems more appropriate to me here, but since I am not a native speaker I thought I should ask.

Comment: It's referring to a *day*, so....

Answer (score 11):

'On' **always** precedes dates.

For example:

- An event took place on the twenty ninth of September, 2014.
- An event took place on September the twenty ninth, 2014.
- An event took place on 29th September, 2014.
- An event took place on September 29th, 2014.
- An event took place on 29 September, 2014.
- An event took place on September 29, 2014.
- An event took place on 2014/09/29.

[**Thumb rules**](http://www.5minuteenglish.com/mar18.htm):

> in + month or year- In March, In 2003
>
> on + date (with the year or without it) or day of the week- On April
>   2, On March 3, 1999, On Saturday
>
> at + clock time, midnight, noon- At 3:30 p.m., At 4:01, At noon
>
> in + season- In the summer, In the winter
>
> in + morning, afternoon, evening- In the morning, In the evening
>
> at + night- At night